# Perform sql query inside my EF Migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following EF Code First model:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to add a migration step to add a new user to my database

Here is what I do:

```
public partial class AddUserAccountJohnDoe : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        var userName = "JOHN.DOE";
        var password = "Welcome2015";

        Sql("insert into Users (UserName, Password) values ('" + userName + "', '" + password + "')");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

The problem: I don't know how to code the sql syntax for adding `Roles` for the added user.

Thanks.

---

EDIT

Below is what I already have in my DB

[image]

[image]

So I need to add a new record in table `UsersRoles` for the newly added user but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have your roles in DB already? If yes i suspect you just need to add something like RoleID to your insert

Comment: I updated my question to respond you. So I don't have any `RoleID` because I may have several roles for one specific user `List<Role> Roles`. Thanks.

Comment: @Bronzato Seed method in this case would be more handy!

Comment: I agree with you Jenish but this is mainly for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update query like this.

```
"declare @uid int;
insert into Users (UserName, Password) values ('" + userName + "', '" + password + "');
select @uid = @@identity;
insert into UsersRoles(UserID, RoleName) values(@uid, 'ADMIN');
insert into UsersRoles(UserID, RoleName) values(@uid, 'USER');"
```